# how to create setup.py script for modules

Tags: python, python-2.7, setup.py

I have the below directory structure for modules :

```
QCsnapshot/
    setup.py
    src/
        checkConnectivity.py
        checkDefaultJobServer.py

        approx. 20 other modules ...
```

`QCsnapshot` directory is located in the eclipse workspace and the `src` directory in it has all the python modules.

I wrote the below `setup.py` script to package and distribute these modules:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(name='snapshot',
      version='1.0',
      description='Snapshot Utility',
      author='Darshan',
      author_email='darshan@python.net',
      url='http://www.python.org/snapshot-url',
      package_dir={'src':'src'}
      #package_data={'':'src'}
     )
```

when I run this `setup.py` file from the windows command prompt I get this output:

```
C:\Users\darshanb\temp\de.ecw.python.QCsnapshot>setup.py install
running install
running build
running install_egg_info
Writing C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\snapshot-1.0-py2.7.egg-info
```

I went through a lot of articles, web pages to learn more on this, but I'm not sure how to proceed further, `__init__.py` file, pypric file, etc. is very confusing

Please tell me how can I create a package of all these modules,
I also have some libraries I have used in the modules like urllib2, lxml, pydobc, etc.
I am not sure how to auto install these libraries

Comment: You're using the `install` command, which installs the package into your current python distro.  But since you talk about "creating a package" it sounds like you might be intending to create some redistributable binary instead.  If so, you should explore some of the other `setup.py` subcommands besides `install`, particularly with ones that start with `bdist_`

Comment: You may want to read a [one](http://www.scotttorborg.com/python-packaging/) or [two](http://guide.python-distribute.org/) good tutorials on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

The setup call needs a py_modules or packages argument, it won’t try to find the Python files automatically.  You’d need to list all modules, or use glob.glob, or reorganize your code a little to have one package instead of many modules (my recommendation).